# Insert multiple rows from one AJAX POST into database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Post header:

```
seasonString: Sommer,Hebst,Frühling,Winter
holidaywishString: 3,4,7,8
```

PHP:

```
//Insert Seasons data
$sqli="INSERT INTO seasons(season)VALUES('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['seasonString'])}')";
$insert=$mysqli->query($sql);
// $userID = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
//Insert Desires data
$sqli="INSERT INTO desires(desires)VALUES('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['holidaywishString'])}')";
$insert=$mysqli->query($sql);
// $userID = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
```

In this case the data is inserted into my database table `tbl_season` on one column:

```
Sommer, Hebst, Frühling, Winter
holidaywishString:3, 4, 7, 8
```

But I want it to be this way:

```
tbl_season;
id    season
-1    Sommer                        
-1    Hebst
-2    winter
-3    hebst
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you want to insert multiple rows then you need to split your values into multiple values and execute multiple `INSERT` statements.

Comment: I actually tried it with Explode() function, but i don't know how it goes with explode() , though i read about it but how to really implement it is my problem. Because of my $_ajax post, which i am getting all the values in one string. so the only option now is to explode and insert it to database.

Comment: What did you try?  How did it not work?  When you used `explode()`, what did you end up with?  How did you try to insert that data into the database?  "I tried but it didn't work" doesn't really describe the problem or show the code you used.

Comment: ' $seasonArray = array();
    $fields = explode(",", $seasonArray);
   foreach($fields  as $season ){
       $sqlSeason = "INSERT INTO seasons(season,iduserinfo)VALUES($season,$userID);
         }
    $insert = $mysqli->query($sqlSeason); 
    $userID = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
    '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$arrSeason = explode(',', $_POST['seasonString']);
    foreach($arrSeason  as $season ){
        $sqlSeason = "INSERT INTO seasons(season,iduserinfo)VALUES('".$mysqli->real_escape_string($season)."','$userID')";
        $mysqli->query($sqlSeason);
    }

/problem solved Thanx a lot